# eliminate noise on specific parts of medical image

Tags: image, image-enhancement

I'm trying to enhance a microscopic image:
[image]

I want only to concentrate on inside the circular area of the image and delete all outside cells, as the following image:

[image]

Any suggestion how I can remove all noise outside the centric circular area without affecting content inside?

Thanks

Comment: It is not entirely clear what you mean by "delete all outside cells" and by "remove noise". Could you please specify how you would like your final image to look like?

Comment: @macco, I updated the final image I want to reach. What image processing techniques you suggest me to consider. Thanks

Comment: @macco, can you please upvote this question if you find it clear enough?